Can i remove x on the corner of a radmessagebox
RadMessageBox.Show("Please fill Username and Password", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Error);

this is the radmessagebox and there is a X on the top right corner of the Rad messagebox .How can i remove the X from this Radmessgebox
tried everything available

What programming language are you using? Please [edit] your question and add it to tags, so that people can find it.
